# mysql Get results of two tables and merge from third table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables where there can only be one entry per id. There is a third table that can have multiple entries for the same id. I can't figure out how to get all of the results from the third table. Here are my tables and data.

```
CREATE table a (
 id int unsigned NOT NULL,
 name varchar(10) default null,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE b (
 id int unsigned NOT NULL,
 addr varchar(10) default null,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE c (
 id int unsigned NOT NULL,
 status varchar(10) default null,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 'bob');
INSERT INTO b VALUES (1,'abc');
INSERT INTO c VALUES (1, 'x'),(1, 'y'),(1, 'z');
```

When I run this

```
SELECT * FROM `a` inner join b using (id) join c using (id) WHERE a.id = 1
```

The result for the above is

```
1 bob abc x
```

What I am trying to do is to get all of the results from the three tables for the given id so I want the results to be something like

```
1 box abc x y z
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I get an error inserting into `c` since you have duplicate primary keys.

Comment: It is not possible to insert more than one row for each `id` in your `c` table, because `id` is the primary key.

Comment: If you remove `PRIMARY KEY (id)` from `c` you'll get 3 rows of results. You could then use `GROUP_CONCAT(c.status)` to combine them in a single row.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table design allows more than one row in the `c` table for each `id` value (which it does not allow in the table you show above), you could get the result this way:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.addr,
  GROUP_CONCAT(c.status SEPARATOR ' ') AS `all_status`
FROM `a` inner join b using (id) join c using (id) 
WHERE a.id = 1
GROUP BY a.id
```